# .aux files missing or not being created in texshop

Tags: pdftex, mac, auxiliary-files

I am using texshop on a mac (version below) and when compiling the main thesis file it is missing out two of the chapters as it 'cant find the aux file'. Why would this be and how can I resolve the issue? I created the files in the same way and they are formatted the same as the previous results chapters so shouldnt be any different.
It continues to write the main file just excluding these chapters.
Can I force create aux files? Or why would they not be created?

Here is some of the code I get on the console:

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX 
    Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
    restricted \write18 enabled.

    No file Main-pages/ch6-results-ch4.aux.
    No file Main-pages/ch7-results-ch5.aux.
```

Please could anyone help - please explain in simplified tex speak with some instructions as I am not the most confident user.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you haven't given many clues but does your main file use `\includeonly` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have shown no source so it is hard to help, but your main document presumably has

```
\include{Main-pages/ch6-results-ch4}
```

if you add such a line you will always get the warning

```
    No file Main-pages/ch6-results-ch4.aux.
```

on the next run of latex, but that run should write `Main-pages/ch6-results-ch4.aux` so on the next run, the warning should go.

If that did not happen then something is preventing the `aux` file.

- TeX might not have write permission to that directory (this would generate an error, which you should show)
- The main document could specify `\includeonly{..}` for some list of files not including `Main-pages/ch6-results-ch4` in which case that chapter will be skipped and no aux file will get written.
- Some other unrelated error caused TeX not to complete properly and write the aux file. In which case you should show the error.
- Some over-aggressive "clean" script from your editor or build pipeline is removing aux files between latex runs. (Don't do that:-)

Comment: Thanks its sorted!